# Does there exist an unique continuous bounded $f$ such that $f(x)= \frac{\sin(f(x))}{2+x^2} - \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+e^x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Does there exist an unique continuous bounded $f$ such that $f(x)= \frac{\sin(f(x))}{2+x^2} - \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+e^x}$?

I wanted to prove this by proving this is a strict contraction and than applying  the fixed point theorem of Banach.

EDIT:
My calculations so far:
$|Tf(x) - Tg(x)| = |\frac{\sin(f(x))}{2+x^2} - \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+e^x}  - \frac{\sin(g(x))}{2+x^2} + \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+e^x}| = |\frac{\sin(f(x))}{2+x^2} - \frac{\sin(g(x))}{2+x^2} | \leq |sin(f(x)) - sin (g(x))| $

But here i get stuck. I can see that because of the continuity of the sinus function : $|f(x)-g(x)|< \delta \rightarrow |sin(f(x)) - sin (g(x))|<\epsilon$. But I do not see how this can help me to make $|sin(f(x)) - sin (g(x))| \leq c |f(x) - g(x)|$.

Comment: Which calculations exactly could you not do?

Comment: proving that d(f(y),f(x))< c d(x,y) with d(x,y) = |x-y| and c in [0,1]

Comment: Are you aware that you have to apply the Banach fixed point theorem to a *function space* and not to the set of real numbers? Start by defining an operator $T$ as $Tf(x) = \frac{\sin(f(x))}{2+x^2} - \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+e^x}$ on the space of bounded continuous functions. Then show that $\Vert Tf - Tg \Vert_\infty \le c \Vert f-g \Vert_\infty$.

Comment: Okey then i can get that $|sin f - sin g| < \epsilon $ but I can not link it to be smaller than $c | f - g | $...

Comment: Update your question with what you tried and where you failed, then we can help you.

Comment: I updated it, thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to apply the Banach fixed point theorem to the space $C_b(\Bbb R)$ of bounded continuous functions with the supremum norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$ and the operator $T: C_b(\Bbb R) \to C_b(\Bbb R)$ defined by
$$
Tf(x) = \frac{\sin(f(x))}{2+x^2} - \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+e^x} \, .
$$

For $f, g \in C_b(\Bbb R)$ and all $x \in \Bbb R$ is
$$
 |Tf(x) - Tg(x)| = \frac{|\sin(f(x))-\sin(g(x))|}{2+x^2}
\le \frac 12 |\sin(f(x))-\sin(g(x))| \\
 \le \frac 12 |f(x) -g(x)| \le \frac 12 \Vert f-g \Vert_\infty \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
 \Vert Tf - Tg \Vert_\infty \le 12 \Vert f-g \Vert_\infty
$$
so that $T$ is a strict contraction.